# What happens if you Forge nothing?

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity

[image: Forge card]

If I play a Forge and for whatever reason choose "none" as the amount of cards trashed (say if I played it via Golem by accident), do I gain anything? I could see 2 possibilities:

- Don't gain because nothing was trashed
- Gain a cost 0

Comment: If you have a gold lamp this could be a good move.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Prosperity rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_361_gameRules.pdf) cover this exact situation:

> Forge - "Any number" includes zero. If you trash no cards, you have to gain
>   a card costing 0 if you can.

Comment: You would have to gain a copper or a curse